# How to conditionally force SSL depending on domain name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have two domain names for my Rails app:  app.example.com, short.net.  The longer domain is the standard domain and requires HTTPS, the shorter domain is a convenience domain for providing short URLs and requires HTTP.

Currently I am forcing SSL:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

But I really only want to force SSL for the longer domain name.  How can I conditionally force SSL depending on domain name?  The short domain name will redirect to the main domain name and then be forced to use SSL.  This would avoid requiring a SSL certificate for the short domain name.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add some configuration to your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   force_ssl if: :ssl_required?

   [...]

   private
   def ssl_required?
     request.host == 'app.example.com'
   end
end
```

Source:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html

Comment: That's pretty funny timing.  I posted my solution below and is pretty close to what you suggested.  I was trying to solve this problem in the routes.rb file, but I think I like this approach better.

Comment: Note that setting `force_ssl` in the controller does not implement the same functionality as `config.force_ssl` in the configuration. In addition to forcing a redirect, the configuration-based version also adds HSTS and secure cookies to every response ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/794252d70990162d14da17ee854ad353e74297ee/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb#L23))

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ':' force_ssl if: :ssl_required?`

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 5 and later you can and should do this via [`ssh_options`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/SSL.html) because `force_ssl` is deprecated in controllers from Rails 6.0 and will be removed in 6.1.

```
config.force_ssl = true
config.ssl_options = {
  redirect: {
    exclude: ->(request) { request.host == 'app.example.com' }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl if: :force_ssl?

private

  def force_ssl?
    if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
      return request.host != CONFIG[:short_host]
    end
    return false
  end
end
```